# Aria2p Attribute Error while canceling download using gid

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot, aria2

I'm trying to cancel the current downloading file using by it gid, but am getting the below error

`Aria2C Error : 'str' object has no attribute 'is_complete'`

```
async def cancel_download(id):
    try:
        await aria2.remove(id)
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error cancelling download with GID {id}: {e}")
        return False
```

```
async def cancel_command(bot, message):
    try:
        id = message.text.replace("/cancel ", "")
        result = await cancel_download(id)
        if result:
            await message.reply_text(f"Download with id {id} cancelled successfully.")
        else:
            await message.reply_text(f"Error cancelling download with id {id}.")
    except ValueError:
        await message.reply_text("Invalid cancel command format.")
```